# A topology for the real line other than the standard one

Tags: general-topology

I am reading the book Introduction to Topology by V. A. Vassiliev. He defines basis as follows:

> A basis of a topology $\mathcal{T} = \{ V_{\alpha} \}_{\alpha \in
>  \Gamma } $ is a subset $\{ W_{\lambda} \}_{\lambda \in \Gamma} \subset
>  \mathcal{T}  $ such that each open set can be represented as the union
>    of a (probably infinite) family of sets from $W_{\lambda}$.

He then gives as an example of a topology: Take $\mathbb{R}$. For the open sets we take those sets that are open in the usual sense, and periodic with period one:

$$ t \in U \iff t + 1 \in U $$

for each open $U$.

MY question is: How is this a topology? I am having hard time trying to see how are the open sets in this topology. Also, what is the basis for this topology?

thanks

Comment: You can always just take all of the open sets to make a basis if you don't have some other idea in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of an open set is $$\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z}\left(n,n+\frac12\right)\;;$$ it’s certainly open in the usual topology, and it’s also periodic with period $1$. You can get a base for the new topology as follows.

Let $\mathscr{B}$ be any base for the usual topology; for instance, $\mathscr{B}$ could be the entire topology, or the set of open intervals, or the set of open intervals with rational endpoints. For each $B\in\mathscr{B}$ let

$$B+\Bbb Z=\{x+n:x\in B\text{ and }n\in\Bbb Z\}\;.$$

If we write $B+n$ for $\{x+n:x\in B\}$, then

$$B+\Bbb Z=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z}(B+n)=\ldots\cup(B-2)\cup(B-1)\cup B\cup(B+1)\cup(B+2)\cup\ldots\;;$$

clearly $B+\Bbb Z$ is open in the usual topology and periodic with period $1$. I claim that $\{B+\Bbb Z:B\in\mathscr{B}\}$ is a base for the new topology.

To see this, let $U$ be open in the new topology. Then $U$ is open in the usual topology, so there is a $\mathscr{B}_U\subseteq\mathscr{B}$ such that $U=\bigcup\mathscr{B}_U$, and I claim that in fact $$U=\bigcup\{B+\Bbb Z:B\in\mathscr{B}_U\}\;;$$ if you can show this, you’ve shown that $\{B+\Bbb Z:B\in\mathscr{B}\}$ is a base for the new topology. For now I’ll leave it to you; it’s not too hard. If you get stuck, leave a comment.

Comment: Thank you very much Brian. If I have a question, I will get back to you. But, this indeed helps a lot.

Comment: @FromCuba: You’re very welcome.

Comment: I have one question: Why is this topology useful? or is it not useful at all ?

Comment: @FromCuba: I don’t know that it actually is; it may just be an example of a non-trivial topology on $\Bbb R$ that’s both different from the usual one and still related to it. I think that this is the first time that I’ve seen it. (It *might* be of some use in connection with families of periodic functions; I’ve not really thought about it.)

Comment: Can be the initial topology for the quotient map $\Bbb R\longrightarrow \Bbb R/(\mod 1)$?

Comment: @Martín-Blas: Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Think of the usual topology of $(0,1)$, a subset $A$ of $(0,1)$ is in this topology if and only if $\cup_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}(A+n)$ is in the topology that you describe

Comment: I think that $[0,1)$ is required. Take $\cdots\cup(-1/4,1/4)\cup\cdots$.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla it's not a full answer, just to show what some open sets should look like. If we take $[0,1)$, then the statement is no longer true. Because $A=[0,1/2)$ is open in $[0,1)$, but $\cup (A+n)$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: You are right...

Answer (score 0):

Examples of open sets
$$\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Z$$
$$\cdots\cup(-2,-3/2)\cup(-1,-1/2))\cup(0,1/2)\cup(1,3/2)\cup\cdots$$
$$\cdots$$